# SAS how to make sas code on a condition-basis

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have this piece of code

```
%macro test(full);

%if &full. = 0 %then %do;
data temp;
set sashelp.air;
run;
%end;

%if &full. = 1 %then %do;
data temp;
set sashelp.air;
where air > 140;
run;
%end;

%mend;

%test(1);
```

or in open code

```
%let full = 1;

%if &full. = 0 %then %do;
data temp;
set sashelp.air;
run;
%end;

%if &full. = 1 %then %do;
data temp;
set sashelp.air;
where air > 140;
run;
%end;
```

is there a way to get something like (this code doesn't work):

```
%macro test(full);

data temp;
set sashelp.air;
%if &full. = 0 %then %do; %sysfunc(call execute('where air>140;'));    %end;
run;
%mend;

%test(1);
```

or in open code, of course. I would like to make the condition working only inside the datastep, avoiding entire datastep repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the unneeded complications.  Also I assume you did not mean to reverse the logic of when the WHERE clause is generated.

```
data temp;
  set sashelp.air;
%if &full.=1 %then %do; 
  where air>140;
%end;
run;
```